# NSFetchResultsController delegate not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have the following code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    // Set up the fetched results controller if needed.
    if (fetchedResultsController == nil) {

 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DiskStory" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isRemoved == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // Set limit
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:25];
        // Set batch size
        [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:50];


        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:kSavedStoryCache];
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
 }
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

in my viewDidLoad I have:

```
 NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
```

I was wondering why my :

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

}
```

delegate, isn't called? I put a break point inside it. Any idea?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint inside `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController`? Are you sure your initialization is being run?

Comment: yes, I put a break point inside there and it goes through until it returns

Comment: And is you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have used self. at wrong places. Please see the code below; i have added comments to the changes

```
 - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    // Set up the fetched results controller if needed.
    if (fetchedResultsController == nil) {

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DiskStory" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isRemoved == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // Set limit
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:25];
        // Set batch size
        [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:50];


        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:kSavedStoryCache];
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;     // -> Shouldn't be self.fetchedResultsController 
 }
    return fetchedResultsController;        // -> Shouldn't be self.fetchedResultsController 
}
```

Also, if you have synthesize your **fetchedResultsController** as follows:

```
fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController
```

Then in `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController` method you should refer to it as _fetchedResultsController

Comment: I have changed it according to your revision and it didn't help.. delegate still not getting called. I put a break point after performing fetchRequest and it is not nil

Comment: I also have synthesize it as fetchedResultsController

Comment: there are 25 records fetched.. no sections

Comment: Are you sure you have register for `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` and that is being executed?

Comment: why should I have NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification?

Comment: Just a thought, does it go to `controllerWillChangeContent` method?

Comment: it goes to none of the delegate method

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem before, it's not called when you call `performFetch` for the first time but only when data in `fetchedResultsController` is actually changed. For instance when you delete object from context that is in this fetch results, delegate will be called.

Comment: bummer... so how can I fix this? my data used for the table view data source is getting the wrong state.. because I need to call reloadData only after fetched is finished

Comment: I solved it by posting notification after initial fetch was done. Then in my `UIViewController` I reloaded my component.

Comment: if you just put it under the performFetch then it is not guaranteed that fetching will be done at that point?

Comment: I meant that after fetch returns - it's done. It's synchronous method.